# Cut nested lists based in another nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of data with nested lists of different length in the following format:

```
dataLis={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4},{2,3,1,5},{4,5,6,7,7,8,9}}
```

Now I have calculated the maximal possible length of all nested lists (based on another data set) and formated that list in the following format

```
lengthLis={{5},{3},{3}}
```

Now I would like to cut the dataLis based on lengthLis. I tried the following formula

```
Outer[Take,dataLis, -lengthLis]
```

but it does not work. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: `MapThread[]` might be more suitable…

Comment: Now that I think about it, you could also use `Inner[]`…

Answer (score 6):

`MapThread` is a good tool for this.

```
dataLis = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9}};
len = {{5}, {3}, {3}};
MapThread[Take, {dataLis, Flatten @ len}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comment by @Guess who it is, `Inner` is a good method to realize your purpose

```
dataLis = 
  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9}};
lengthLis = {{5}, {3}, {3}};

First@
  Inner[Take, dataLis, lengthLis, List]
(*or Inner[Take, dataLis, lengthLis, Sequence] directly*)
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

Comment: I like `Inner[Take, dataLis, lengthLis, Sequence]` :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Yes, I also like it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
(#[[;; #2]]) & @@@ Transpose[{dataLis, Flatten@lengthLis}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Take @@@ ({dataLis, Flatten@lengthLis}\[Transpose])
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `TakeList`**: (* introduced 14 Sep 2017 *)

```
dataLis = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 
   8, 9}};
len = {{5}, {3}, {3}};

Sequence @@@ MapThread[TakeList, {dataLis, len}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}}

Answer (score 1):

```
♯0 = #[[;; #2]] & @@@ ({#, ## & @@@ #2}) &;

♯0[dataLis, lengthLis]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `MapThread` and `Span`:

```
d = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9}};
l = {{5}, {3}, {3}};

MapThread[d[[#1, ;; #2[[1]]]] &, {Range[Length@d], l}]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll` and `Table`:

```
d /. x : {__List} :> Table[x[[i, ;; l[[i, 1]]]], {i, Length@x}]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

`MapApply` came with V 13.1

```
MapApply[First @* TakeList] @ Transpose[{dataLis, lengthLis}]
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 6}}